# How to put std::set into std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap, stdset

I declared std: map below:

```
std::map<std::string, std::set<unsigned char*>> FilesMap;

int InsertData(unsigned char* name)
{
  // here i try to insert pair with name above and clear std::set
   FilesMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::set<unsigned char*>>(std::string((char*)name), std::set<unsigned char*>()));
}
```

But I have many errors like:

> Error 16  error C2676: binary '<': 'const std::string' does not define
>   this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined
>   operator  c: \program files (x86)\microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\vc\include\xfunctional

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are we to assume that you're using C++11 or that you actually have a space in your `>>` closing token?

Comment: It compiles correctly using VS2010 in my machine. Well, assuming you have included `<string>`, `<set>` and `<map>`.

Comment: @MarkB MSVC understands `>>` in templates for a very long time.. Long before it was standardized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this horribly long line

```
FilesMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::set<unsigned char*>>(std::string((char*)name), std::set<unsigned char*>()));
```

can be simplified if you use std::make_pair function, which will deduce template arguments.

```
FilesMap.insert(std::make_pair(std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>name)), std::set<unsigned char*>()));
```

Second, you could make a typedef for your set so as to simplify the above line even more

```
typedef std::set<unsigned char*> mySetType;
std::map<std::string, mySetType>> FilesMap;
 FilesMap.insert(std::make_pair(std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>name)), MySetType()));
```

And lastly, and most importantly, I believe the reason that the compiler is unable to find a suitable `operator <` for std::string is that you forgot to `#include<string>`

Comment: You don't address the cause of the error, he didn't want a comparison, its a template parsing error

Comment: However using the simpler form with `make_pair` removes the problematic `>>` and should still fix the problem.

Comment: @jozefg: Actually, you're wrong and I'm right. The error is that the compiler cannot find operator < for the strings, to use as map key. Not the closing >> which MSVC handles OK for a long time now...

Answer (score 0):

A requirement for using std::map, is that the key type has to have an `operator <` . It seems you are getting an error with regards to std::string not having this operator. Make sure you have included the string header `#include <string>`.